# How to get rid of this error message?

Tags: linux, centos5, modprobe

I have this error message popping up in my `/var/log/messages` file:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.33.7.2-rt30-xxxx-std-ipv4-64/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

My OS is CentOS 5.5 with my own compiled kernel, it's working fine so I know it's not causing any problems so I was wondering if it was possible to disable this message somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the module by adding the following to `/etc/modprobe.conf`:

```
alias rt30 off
```